# how do i create a username and password for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Hi i have installed locally xampp php and mysql. Im reading and it says about having a username and a password. I dont login at all, i just press start to both apache and php. How i put a username and password?

I know it might be a silly question but i have googled and i dont understand... how to do it and if i can do it locally.

Thanks!

Comment: a default xampp installation has an account "root" with no password you can use. obviously this isn't advised for security reasons !

Comment: With XAMPP you should access http://localhost/security/ and set the password for root etc. For accessing databases you should create own users. Never ever use in production root as user!

Comment: thanks thedom :) How do i create a user for a database?

Answer (score 0):

apache or php do not have credentials, only mysql has. usually with xamp comes phpmyadmin which lets you manage users for mysql, too. In my case, it was preconfigured just to work. user for mysql was root, password blank. Maybe you should change that ;)

Access phpmyadmin via http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

In the directory of phpmyadmin (called phpMyAdmin in your xampp dir) there is a config.inc.php where the username that phpMyAdmin uses is configured. If you change the password via phpMyAdmin you have to edit it here, too.

Comment: thanks :) i have changed the password but i cant edit the user. How do i do that?

Comment: you should not edit the root user (I´m not even sure if it works), since root is the super user you need for administration. You could create an additional user (e.g. called apache) and use this one in your php web apps, or if you like you could even create one user per web-app you run on the machine. The advantage in this case is that you can limit the rights of those user to specific databases and specific operations in these databases.

Comment: How do i create an aditional user? CREATE USER user_name?

Comment: It works with CREATE USER, but you need to enter the password and the privileges as well. I recommend you to use phpMyAdmin, the tab is called privileges. Otherwise, refer to mysql documentation

Comment: Have you considered accepting the answer if it solved your problem?